# How to merge heatmap with goplot in R ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2, merge, heatmap, ggpubr, pheatmap

I created a heatmap using pheatmap package as follows:

```
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

a=pheatmap(test)
a
```

[image: heatmap]

And I created GOplot using GOplot package as follows:
dput(circ)

```
structure(list(category = c("Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms", 
"Enriched Terms", "Enriched Terms"), ID = c("inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", 
"inflammatory response", "inflammatory response", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "T cell activation", "T cell activation", 
"T cell activation", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"cytokine mediated signaling pathway", "cytokine mediated signaling pathway", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", "T cell proliferation", 
"T cell proliferation", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", "wound healing", 
"response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", 
"response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", 
"response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", "response to progesterone", 
"response to progesterone", "response to progesterone"), term = c("GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", "GO:0006954", 
"GO:0006954", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", 
"GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0042110", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", "GO:0019221", 
"GO:0019221", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", 
"GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", 
"GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", 
"GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", 
"GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", "GO:0042098", 
"GO:0042098", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", "GO:0042060", 
"GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", 
"GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", "GO:0032570", 
"GO:0032570"), count = c(72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L), genes = c("CDO1", "HLA-DRB1", "ACP5", "HMGB2", 
"HMOX1", "ADCY1", "F7", "CD163", "TYROBP", "FCER1G", "CIITA", 
"FCGR3A", "CXCL9", "CCL2", "CCR1", "CCL5", "MMP3", "ABCC2", "ALOX15", 
"SGK1", "FPR3", "APOD", "SCUBE1", "SERPINC1", "PDE5A", "IL1B", 
"CYBB", "SLAMF8", "TRAF3IP2", "IL18", "METRNL", "IL17B", "IRAK2", 
"IL20RB", "IRF5", "PTAFR", "IL1RL2", "ITGB2", "PTGIR", "ITGB6", 
"PDCD4", "GGT1", "PTN", "BMPR1B", "PLA2G2D", "SPHK1", "CXCL17", 
"SCG2", "SIGLEC10", "TRIM55", "C1QA", "LILRB4", "RHBDF2", "SOCS3", 
"GRN", "RELB", "PSTPIP1", "ECM1", "NFAM1", "BCL6B", "ACE2", "CD6", 
"CD14", "TIMP1", "GPR68", "CD36", "CD74", "ADGRE5", "TNFAIP3", 
"LYZ", "HCK", "CD96", "ERBB2", "HLA-DQA1", "HLA-DQB1", "HLA-DRB1", 
"ZNF683", "EOMES", "ICOS", "FCER1G", "CCL2", "CCL5", "WAS", "RASAL3", 
"SOCS1", "PDE5A", "IL1B", "STX11", "IL7", "TRAF3IP2", "TNFRSF9", 
"IL18", "TNFRSF14", "IL20RB", "IRF1", "ITGAX", "IL1RL2", "ITGB2", 
"ITK", "LAPTM5", "BMP4", "CLEC4F", "PLA2G2D", "LILRB4", "SH2B3", 
"VTCN1", "RELB", "SH2D2A", "TSPAN32", "RUNX3", "CD6", "CD7", 
"LMO1", "CD86", "CD70", "CD74", "PAX1", "MPZL2", "LEF1", "FCER1G", 
"IFITM3", "CXCL9", "CCL2", "CCR1", "CCL5", "CNTFR", "CD300LF", 
"PYDC1", "MST1R", "SOCS1", "IL1B", "IL17RD", "IL2RB", "IL7", 
"IL10RA", "TRAF3IP2", "IL15RA", "IL18", "TNFRSF14", "IRAK2", 
"IL20RB", "IRF1", "IRF5", "IL1RL2", "LAPTM5", "PXDN", "IL1RAPL2", 
"SPHK1", "CXCL17", "LILRB4", "SH2B3", "ECM1", "GREM2", "CD70", 
"CD74", "TNFAIP3", "HCK", "ERBB2", "HLA-DQA1", "HLA-DRB1", "CCL5", 
"RASAL3", "PDE5A", "IL1B", "TNFRSF9", "IL18", "TNFRSF14", "IL20RB", 
"IRF1", "ITGAX", "ITGB2", "LAPTM5", "BMP4", "PLA2G2D", "LILRB4", 
"VTCN1", "SH2D2A", "TSPAN32", "CD6", "LMO1", "CD86", "CD70", 
"HGFAC", "NRG1", "ERBB2", "HMOX1", "F7", "FCER1G", "FCGR3A", 
"CCL2", "C1QTNF1", "VAV3", "FGG", "MMP3", "POU2F3", "ALOX15", 
"MIA3", "WAS", "ENPP4", "SCUBE1", "SERPINC1", "IL1B", "GATA2", 
"ITGA5", "ITGB6", "BMP4", "DST", "LILRB4", "IL24", "KRT6A", "RAP2B", 
"SH2B3", "DSP", "TSPAN32", "TFPI", "TIMP1", "EVPLL", "CD36", 
"TNFAIP3", "PAX7", "PARD3", "NRG1", "ERBB2", "CCL2", "SOCS1", 
"RELN", "PTN", "SPHK1", "DSG1", "ABHD2", "SOCS3", "OXTR"), logFC = c(-2.737960452, 
1.241037398, 1.374760702, -1.103596949, 1.079758824, 3.086032109, 
-2.877651668, 1.09476118, 1.118517102, 1.041377427, 1.319558299, 
1.118681141, 2.891440638, 1.122498237, 1.92052302, 1.54657149, 
2.538427301, -2.69483845, -3.915575094, 1.319202149, 1.697645266, 
-2.86918927, 2.1371583, -5.659311147, -1.53119513, 1.945184259, 
1.347387517, 1.722650321, -1.180236204, 1.21734454, 1.084121694, 
-5.283056691, 1.205271542, 1.917439533, 1.256984968, 1.180701005, 
-3.027851614, 1.24994078, 1.527263076, -2.185935071, -1.146129256, 
-5.061405849, -3.572421784, 4.006705524, 2.224401737, 1.169631321, 
-3.463052584, -2.572606019, 1.94368823, -5.940020275, 1.152347835, 
1.716108464, 1.201977508, 1.706652811, 1.062033751, 1.233980975, 
1.310927918, 1.903484885, 1.115666204, 1.293787307, -3.656400355, 
1.959492212, 1.067545802, 1.499824047, 1.404434777, -2.937891421, 
1.107773701, 1.043144439, 1.777494393, 1.646834437, 1.156112282, 
1.10944754, -4.210238561, 1.865313935, 1.513262912, 1.241037398, 
1.782577274, 2.516774087, 2.339406632, 1.041377427, 1.122498237, 
1.54657149, 1.191237579, 1.472211185, 1.857872456, -1.53119513, 
1.945184259, 1.511626606, -1.727937842, -1.180236204, 1.911680124, 
1.21734454, 1.334667618, 1.917439533, 1.484782869, 1.212649627, 
-3.027851614, 1.24994078, 1.811227395, 1.233641, -2.12693152, 
-1.836124452, 2.224401737, 1.716108464, 1.035261508, -2.405733686, 
1.233980975, 1.267228904, 2.207264277, 1.410751117, 1.959492212, 
2.971479523, -4.825751399, 1.047624972, 2.837308276, 1.107773701, 
-4.987747449, -1.74915527, 1.247360205, 1.041377427, 1.058227706, 
2.891440638, 1.122498237, 1.92052302, 1.54657149, -4.172482769, 
1.333487402, 4.152707357, -1.785658712, 1.857872456, 1.945184259, 
-1.95196654, 1.941367702, -1.727937842, 1.057464494, -1.180236204, 
1.020161179, 1.21734454, 1.334667618, 1.205271542, 1.917439533, 
1.484782869, 1.256984968, -3.027851614, 1.233641, 1.788558045, 
-5.462904275, 1.169631321, -3.463052584, 1.716108464, 1.035261508, 
1.903484885, -2.291272692, 2.837308276, 1.107773701, 1.777494393, 
1.156112282, -4.210238561, 1.865313935, 1.241037398, 1.54657149, 
1.472211185, -1.53119513, 1.945184259, 1.911680124, 1.21734454, 
1.334667618, 1.917439533, 1.484782869, 1.212649627, 1.24994078, 
1.233641, -2.12693152, 2.224401737, 1.716108464, -2.405733686, 
1.267228904, 2.207264277, 1.959492212, -4.825751399, 1.047624972, 
2.837308276, 5.993222336, -2.978513041, -4.210238561, 1.079758824, 
-2.877651668, 1.041377427, 1.118681141, 1.122498237, 1.376906496, 
-1.914010292, -5.261606201, 2.538427301, -3.653580929, -3.915575094, 
-1.138879528, 1.191237579, 1.613578374, 2.1371583, -5.659311147, 
1.945184259, -1.574242178, 1.141089282, -2.185935071, -2.12693152, 
-1.138578308, 1.716108464, 4.7309855, 2.559918081, 1.135394507, 
1.035261508, -1.581412595, 2.207264277, -1.836137414, 1.499824047, 
-5.643250914, -2.937891421, 1.777494393, -4.220593474, -1.301224439, 
-2.978513041, -4.210238561, 1.122498237, 1.857872456, -2.263900849, 
-3.572421784, 1.169631321, -4.277817031, 1.778735721, 1.706652811, 
-2.319315751), adj_pval = c(3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 
3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 3.96e-05, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 
0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00237, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 
0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 
0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 
0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 
0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 
0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00542, 0.00593, 
0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 
0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 
0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 
0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00593, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 0.00631, 
0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 
0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682, 0.00682), zscore = c(3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 
3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.77123616632825, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 
3.64662478744736, 3.64662478744736, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 3.24442842261525, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 0.160128153805087, 
-0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, 
-0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, 
-0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764, -0.301511344577764)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-232L))
```

and

```
b=GOBar(circ, display = 'multiple')
b
```

[image: goplot]

Next, I wanted to merge a, b as single figure.
I tried

```
ggarrange(a,b,labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 1, nrow = 1)
```

But it ouput only Goplot as b keeping a as blank:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `pheatmap` returns a `pheatmap` object. Basically it is a `list` which besides the plot contains several other elements. Hence, to combine the heatmap with another plot you have to extract the element which contains the "plot", which is the element called `gtable`:

Note:  IMHO the issue is not related to your `GOplot` so for the sake of simplicity I replaced it with a simple ggplot based on mtcars.

```r
library(pheatmap)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(123)

a <- pheatmap(test)

b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

ggarrange(a$gtable, b, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `patchwork`? You can combine many types of figures in different ways with it.

https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/